# Test permission denied not catched

Tags: django

I try to check with unittests if it is possible to access a certain url without the proper permissions.

When I wrote the test everything worked correctly. I don't know if the error started to occurs after a Django update because I didn't check the test after the update and just started to write new tests which failed. So I checked my old test which is now failing too.

```
class MemberTestMethods(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Create user
        user = User.objects.create_user('temp', 'temp@temp.tld', 'temppass')
        user.first_name = 'temp_first'
        user.last_name = 'temp_last'
        user.save()

        # login with user
        self.client.login(username='temp', password='temppass')

        # Create member
        member = Member.objects.create(salutation=Member.MR, first_name='Temp', last_name='Temp')
        member.save()

    def test_member_list_permission(self):
        "User should only access member list if view permission is set"

        user = User.objects.get(username='temp')

        response = self.client.get(reverse('members:list'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)

        user.user_permissions.add(Permission.objects.get(codename='view_member'))

        response = self.client.get(reverse('members:list'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

After running `python manage.py test` I get the following error

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
WARNING:django.request:Forbidden (Permission denied): /de/reporting/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/***/.virtualenvs/pyVerein/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
File "/home/***/.virtualenvs/pyVerein/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/***/.virtualenvs/pyVerein/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/***/.virtualenvs/pyVerein/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/***/.virtualenvs/pyVerein/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/***/.virtualenvs/pyVerein/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 84, in dispatch
    return self.handle_no_permission()
File "/home/***/.virtualenvs/pyVerein/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 43, in handle_no_permission
    raise PermissionDenied(self.get_permission_denied_message())
django.core.exceptions.PermissionDenied
```

Previously the test ran successfully while checking for HTTP-Code 403 like it is describe in the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#exceptions)

The full Sourceode is available at Github (https://github.com/HamburgerJungeJr/pyVerein/tree/pyReportJasper/pyVerein/members)

Am I missing a change in the Django-Test system?

Comment: That's for what tests are, you broke your view and your test is yelling at you! If your test were ok, don't try to fix your test, try to repair the code you have broke (whether updating Django or making some change)

Comment: No.The documentation says that PermissionDenied errors are changed to HTTP-403 responses so that I can check the status_code. But the exception raises in the testclient which is not what is stated in the documentation.

Comment: I just checked: With Django 2.0.10 the exception does not occure. After updating to Django 2.1 the exception occures,

Comment: So,  you have to update the view, handle the exeption and return status code 403. Yuor test worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. The PyReportJasper-package set the global logging level to INFO. After changing this the error is gone.